# Set up catalina environment in ubuntu

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, ubuntu, tomcat7

I have set up Tomcat7 and now i am being told to set up the CLASSPATH for Java servlets in the .cshrc file.But i don't have any .cshrc files.SO where do i set them up.Will setting it up in bashrc work?Also my Catalina in in /etc so i should just point to the Catalina folder in /etc right?

The path of my Catalina folder is:

```
/etc/tomcat7
```

So the path set up by me should be:

```
setenv CATALINA=/etc/tomcat7
```

However there are 2 tomcat7 folders one in /etc and another in /var.
What should i do?

I am trying to implement the last section on this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-environment-setup.htm.But it is highly unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like someone expects you are running `csh`, ubuntu has `bash` as a default shell. You could certainly install `csh` and set it as your shell, but I don't think you're asking how to do [that](https://askubuntu.com/a/484573/214223). I think you want to edit `/etc/profile` (or `~/.profile`) and add

```
export CATALINA=/etc/tomcat7
```

You should also review the Ubuntu community documentation for [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: I want to run servlets and so i need to set up the catalina environment variable.